# Regular Expression Extract Relevant Info from Email

Tags: regex, node.js, mechanicalturk

Given the following text:

```
Greetings from Amazon Mechanical Turk,

You are receiving this email because you subscribed to be notified when
certain events related to your HITs or Qualifications occurred.

Specific event information is shown below:

    Event Type: HITExpired
    Event Time: 2014-10-14T08:00:05Z
    HIT Type ID: 3UY3BQX0VV1BL434D90TUMKT09C20F
    HIT ID: 37VHPF5VYC3MCKRQBEXYFY64LO48CJ


Sincerely,
Amazon Mechanical Turk
https://requestersandbox.mturk.com
410 Terry Avenue North
SEATTLE, WA 98109-5210 USA
```

How could I extract the information to end up with:

```
{
    'Event Type': 'HITExpired',
    'Event Time': '2014-10-14T08:00:05Z',
    'HIT Type ID': '3UY3BQX0VV1BL434D90TUMKT09C20F',
    'HIT ID': '37VHPF5VYC3MCKRQBEXYFY64LO48CJ'
}
```

Comment: It may be easier to just send these notifications to an SQS queue, which would send the relevant fields in json automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {}; str.replace(/^\s+([^:\n]*):\s*(.*)$/mg, function(_, k, v) { a[k] = v; })
```

After this, `a` will be the structure you want. `replace` will call the function once for each match, the pattern being a line starting with some spaces, a key, a colon, maybe some more spaces, and then a value; the function will just stuff the key and the value into the object `a`.

EDIT: fixed silly error. Also, I assumed only the desired lines would be indented.

Comment: Not quite, this is the result:
`{ 'You are receiving this email because you subscribed to be notified when\ncertain events related to your HITs or Qualifications occurred.\n\n\nSpecific event information is shown below': 'Event Type: HITExpired',
'Event Time': '2014-10-14T08:00:05Z',
'HIT Type ID': '3UY3BQX0VV1BL434D90TUMKT09C20F',
'HIT ID': '37VHPF5VYC3MCKRQBEXYFY64LO48CJ',
'Sincerely,\nAmazon Mechanical Turk\nhttps': '//requestersandbox.mturk.com' }`

Comment: Looking for 4 spaces fixes it: `/^\s\s\s\s+([^:]*):\s*(.*)$/mg`

Comment: Yeh, sorry about that. Four spaces should do it too.

Comment: One problem is that `\s` can match newlines too, so you will obtain unexpected results. you can avoid the problem using `[^\S\n]` instead: `^[^\S\n]+([^:\n]*):[^\S\n]*(.*)$`. An other question is: is the use of the replace method appropriate here?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: True, on both counts. `[^\S\n]` is better, definitely - I never properly tested. And while `while` with `exec` might be strictly better, or looping on `split` for lines, `replace` makes it into a one-liner, even if it is one I wrote quickly (too quickly) as I packed to leave. :) But it illustrates the principle, at least.

Comment: @Amadan: It's clearly a lack in Javascript (and in PHP too) that you can't map the match results in a functional programming way.